# Exponents and identities in Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In a group, prove that $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$ for all $a \in G$.

I know that it is obviously $a$; however, I'm not sure how to prove it. Also, I know that I have to incorporate the identity $e$ somehow.

Comment: What is the defining property of $(a^{-1})^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $a^{-1}$ is the inverse of $a$, then by definition, $a\cdot a^{-1}=e$ and $a^{-1}\cdot a=e$.

And when you look at these two equality in another aspect, this time recognize $a^{-1}$ as a protagonist, it is saying that

$\underbrace{a}_{\text{something times $a^{-1}$}}\cdot a^{-1}=e$ and

$a^{-1}\cdot \underbrace{a}_{\text{$a^{-1}$ times something}}=e$.

Hence by the definition of the inverse of an element in a group, $a^{-1}$ has the inverse $a$, and it is denoted as $({a^{-1}})^{-1}=a$.

(Notice that this proof has adopt the fact that the inverse of an element in a group must unique.)

Answer (score 0):

By definition the inverse of $a$ is the element $a^{-1}$ such that $aa^{-1}=e$ and from this definition you can easily prove that $a^{-1}$ commute with $a$, i.e. we have also $a^{-1}a=e$ ( this is a consequence of $ae=ea=a$) and we can also prove that the inverse is unique.

So, the inverse of $a^{-1}$ is the element $(a^{-1})^{-1}$ such that
$$
a^{-1}(a^{-1})^{-1}=e 
$$
but since  the inverse is unique  and we know that $a^{-1}a=e$,  we have $(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$